# Regex improvement. Accept dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I apply a regex on a field to suppress special characters :

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

It works perfectly exept that it also suppress dots (`.`) . I'm having trouble with the regex to add just an exception to allow dots.

How should I modify this regex to accept dots while deleting other special characters ?

Comment: have you tried just adding a `.` in the character class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the dot to the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s.]+/g, '')
```

Also, for a slight performance improvement, I've added a `+` quantifier so the regex can replace multiple characters in a single operation instead of replacing each single character one at a time. The case insensitivity modifier can be removed as well.

Comment: @EoiFirst: No problem, we're all learning something or other :) The tutorial I linked to is really good - check it out.